# how do I get information about an authenticated user at Node JS

Tags: express

how can I get the information of the currently authenticated user? for example, I could get it with Auth::user() on laravel framework. How do i do on node js(express js) ?

Thank you.

Comment: You can get it from the request object simply by logging `console.log(req.user)`

Comment: Which authentication method are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on how the authentication works is working on your Frontend. Most of the time, you will be having access to request object which contains a bunch of information regarding the user and the operation.

Usually, Authentication is based  of two types:

- Cookie based authentication
- Token Based Authentication (JWT)

Usually these information is passed in the form of headers.
Sometimes custom headers can be used to send this info, can sometimes it is sent in Authentication header.

Lets Assume you are using token based authentication,
In this case, you should be receving header named,

- Authencation: Bearer "a_really_long_string_token".

Usually this token contains a lot of information and will require the secret keys which are used to encrypt it.

Comment: thank you Chirag Saini.